# Subcomponent not updating on dropdown selection via onConfigure

Tags: java, wicket

I have a dropdown that, depending on the selection, updates some disclaimer text on the page. The dropdown and disclaimer each are its own Panel (own markup and component). I want to make it so that the first time the page loads, the disclaimer is not shown. Anytime a selection from the dropdown is made, the disclaimer shows.

DropDownPanel.java

```
private boolean firstTimeLoaded = true;

...

disclaimerPanel = new DisclaimerPanel( "disclaimer", contactModel, firstTimeLoaded );
disclaimerPanel.setOutputMarkupId( true );
disclaimerPanel.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag( true );

...

dropDownChoice.getInternalComponent().add( new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior( "onchange" )
    {
        @Override
        protected void onUpdate( AjaxRequestTarget ajaxRequestTarget )
        {
            // METHOD 1 
            disclaimerPanel = new Disclaimer( "disclaimer", contactModel, !firstTimeLoaded );
            disclaimerPanel.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag( true );
            disclaimerPanel.setOutputMarkupId( true );

            // METHOD 2
            // remove code from METHOD 1 as onConfigure should set visibility of DisclaimerPanel using addComponent

            ajaxRequestTarget.addComponent( disclaimerPanel );
            ajaxRequestTarget.addChildren( disclaimerPanel, Component.class );

        }
```

DisclaimerPanel.java

```
private boolean firstTimeLoaded;

public DisclaimerPanel( String id, IModel<Contact> contactModel, boolean firstTimeLoaded )
    {
        ...
        this.firstTimeLoaded = firstTimeLoaded;
    }

@Override
    protected void onConfigure()
    {
        setVisible( !firstTimeLoaded );
    }
```

I've tried two ways but both don't work (METHOD 1, METHOD 2). From breakpoints, `onConfigure` runs the first time and hides the disclaimer correctly. When I make a selection; however, the constructor of `DisclaimerPanel` with `firstTimeLoaded` as `false` but `onConfigure` isn't executed. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What Wicket Version are you using? If it is 8 or never `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior( "onchange")` needs to be changed to `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior( "change")`. Since wicket 6.0 they changed it so that you no longer need the leading 'on' in the event name. up until wicket 8 they supported both, since wicket 8.0 the leading 'on' is no longer supported.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I believe it's version 4 (1.4.23)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create a new instance of DisclaimerPanel in onUpdate(). You just need to switch its `firstTimeLoaded` value and then add `disclaimerPanel` to the AjaxRequestTarget. You can add a setter for `firstTimeLoaded` to DisclaimerPanel, or use an `IModel<Boolean>` instead of plain `boolean` as constructor parameter.

In your code, where you create a new instance, you need to replace the old one with: `replace(disclaimerPanel)`. This is needed because in Wicket a Page is like a tree data structure - the page is the root, and it may have branches - its first-level components, and they may have their own branches - their children components, etc. So here you create a new instance of DisclaimerPanel but you don't add it to any parent component. You need to use `parent.replace(disclaimerPanel)` and then add the `disclaimerPanel` to the AjaxRequestTarget so that Wicket renders its HTML in the Ajax response.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question.
I've added 
`firstTimeLoaded = false;`
`addOrReplace( autodepositPanel );`
and removed the lines from METHOD 1 but it still doesn't work. I've added `disclaimerPanel` to the AjaxRequestTarget in my original code. What is the difference between this and `addOrReplace`?